# Powershell output in json format

Tags: powershell

I need to get the details of a particular software for eg: Chrome in json format.
The below command shows output of all the softwares in Json format.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | select-object name,version,vendor,InstallDate,InstallLocation | ConvertTo-Json
```

But I need to grep only for chrome. I get the output as below, but it is not in json format.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | select-object name,version,vendor,InstallDate | Select-String 'Chrome'

@{name=Google Chrome; version=60.0.3xxx; vendor=Google, Inc.; InstallDate=20180909}
```

Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products need to be filtered with `Where-Object`. Get-WmiObject is superceded by Get-CimInstance in PowerShell 3.0.

```
Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Product |
    Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Vendor,InstallDate |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Chrome' }

Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Product |
    Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Vendor,InstallDate |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Chrome' } |
    ConvertTo-Json

PS C:\> Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Product |
>>     Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Vendor,InstallDate |
>>     Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Chrome' } |
>>     ConvertTo-Json
>>
{
    "Name":  "Google Chrome",
    "Version":  "84.0.4147.135",
    "Vendor":  "Google LLC",
    "InstallDate":  "20191126"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using win32_product, see [win32_product-is-evil](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/)

Here's an alternative which should run a lot faster:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, 
                 HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*chrome*'} |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | 
    ConvertTo-Json
```

Output

```
{
"DisplayName":  "Google Chrome",
"DisplayVersion":  "79.0.3945.130",
"Publisher":  "Google LLC",
"InstallDate":  "20191113"
}
```

If you want to search for 32 bit applications, use the following registry:

```
HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

Comment: This would be nice, but Google Chrome does not appear in the output on my machine. $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString() => 5.1.17763.1007

Comment: Maybe you have the 32bit version? See my revision.

Comment: [Environment]::Is64BitProcess => True

Comment: I meant the 32bit version of Chrome (installed on a 64bit OS).

Comment: Yes, is is Chrome 32-bit.  It does appear iwhen using `Wow6432Node`. I am not sure if the OP wants to search for everything twice.

Comment: True, but I don't think its a big overhead, I have updated the example as you can simply combine the search paths

Comment: That will work on Windows. PowerShell runs on Linux and Mac. I have heard no concept of the Windows registry (HKLM and friends) going to those platforms.

Comment: Wow, we are going way off topic here, win32_product won't work on Mac or Linux which was the original question.